# hardship veiwing PDF and trying adobe reader

Tags: pdf, adobe

On the immigration canada web page viewing PDF and some of them worked and some gave me this notice:

```
Please wait...
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type of document.
You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows®, Mac, or Linux® by
visiting http://www.adobe.com/go/reader_download.
For more assistance with Adobe Reader visit http://www.adobe.com/go/acrreader.
Windows is either a registered trademark or a trademark of Microsoft Corporation in the United States and/or other countries. Mac is a trademark
of Apple Inc., registered in the United States and other countries. Linux is the registered trademark of Linus Torvalds in the U.S. and other
countrie
```

on abobe's page there is no linux or ubuntu option. i am using ubuntu 14.04
what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Because Adobe Reader for Linux is version 9, and Adobe has already phased out Acrobat/Reader 9, it is no longer accessible through the get.adobe.com site. The information on the Immigration Canada website is also dated (when you click on the download link, you get redirected to the get.adobe.com site).

However, there are third parties which have redistribution rights for Adobe Reader for Linux. Search engines are your friend.